# What is the difference between a young coconut and a white coconut?

Tags: coconut

I am reading conflicting information.

https://www.friedas.com/products/young-coconut/ ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20210503001646/https://www.friedas.com/the-ultimate-coconut-guide/)) says young coconut and white coconut are different:

> Young coconuts, white coconuts and brown coconuts all come from the same coconut palm, they just differ by stage of maturity.

https://www.chowhound.com/post/white-coconut-292062 ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20210503002124/https://www.chowhound.com/post/white-coconut-292062)) says they are the same:

> The white coconuts are the young coconuts with the green outer skin removed.

Which one is right?

---

Young coconut:

[image]

White coconut:

[image]

Comment: To me your quotes say the same. White coconuts are young coconuts with the (still green) skin removed.

Comment: @Willeke the first quote says that they differ by stage of maturity.

Comment: We have white coconut available here in Mexican supermarkets and I find the meat firmer than streetside drinking coconut which would be too fragile to peel.  Too many regional terms to be precise